# how to find whether a node has more than one revision?

Tags: 7, nodes

How could I find whether a node has more than one revision. I use `node_load($nid)` and get a `$node` object.
How can I achieve this using the object? What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [`node_revision_list($node)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_revision_list/7) function?

> This returns a list of all the existing revision numbers.

You can pass the current node and it will return list of all revisions.